# coredump while printing character string

Tags: c, pointers

I have 3 questions:

1. Why would `userHostPairs[count]=line` give undesired result as explained in the comment in the code?
2. Why would the program crash while printing?
3. What is the way to pass userHostPairs as an arg to readEnv() so that it can be used in main?

```
     #define MAX_HOSTS 100
     #define MAX_LINE_SIZE 100

     void readEnvList()
     {
            FILE *fp;

            char  line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
            char* userHostPairs[MAX_HOSTS];

            if((fp = fopen("somefile", "r")) == NULL)
            {
                //ERR_StdReportAndReturn_2(OPIGN_FILE_FAILURE ,"write", schScriptFileName);
                printf("Failed to open the file\n");
            }

            int count =0;
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL ) {
                    //userHostPairs[count]=line;  --Assignment like this gives undefined results. e.g. at the end of the loop userHostPairs[0] & userHostPairs[1] both contain the last fetched line from file.
                    strcpy(userHostPairs[count],line);
                    count++;
            }

            printf("%s",userHostPairs[0]); //CORE DUMP here

    }
    int main()
    {
            readEnvList();
    }
```

Comment: You never allocate memory for `userHostPairs[0]`, put something like `userHostPairs[count] = malloc(MAX_LINE_SIZE);` in the loop.

Comment: If I only had a dollar for each time this pitfall claimed another new C programmer, I could retire comfortably.... `char *userHostPairs[MAX_HOSTS];` declares an *array-of-pointers*. But each pointer does not yet hold as its value a valid starting memory address to storage sufficient to hold what you want to copy there. You have to initialize each of the pointers so they point to valid storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code

```
  strcpy(userHostPairs[count],line);
```

you're trying to write into unitialized pointer(s) (`userHostPairs[count]`), which points to indeterminate address. The memory location is thus *invalid* in context of your program and attempt to write into invalid memory location invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to either

- Assign valid memory locations to each of `userHostPairs[count]`, so that each elements point to a valid block of memory (example: using [`malloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or family), and then use `strcpy()` as you have done.
- Use [`strdup()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to have the copying done.